# How do I add php support to apache2 without breaking my current installation?

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I run apache2 with wsgi (for a django-app) on an ubuntu box. I want to use Nagios for server monitoring, and for this purpose it seems I have to add php support to apache.

When I installed apache2, I did this:

apt-get install apache2 apache2.2-common apache2-mpm-worker apache2-threaded-dev libapache2-mod-wsgi python-dev

What is the best way for me to add php support to apache2 without breaking my current installation and configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the additional packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: I'd add that if the installation is important enough to wring your hands in worry that things will break, having a good backup is probably a good idea...then if it did break you just restore the system.